# Custom search for text under cursor

Tags: search, highlighting, unicode

I would like to write a custom elisp function that searches for a few variants of unicode text **under a cursor** and highlights their occurrences in the currently open file.

For e.g. if my text is `helloम्` (it ends with bytes `U2350+U2381`) the function should search a modified version of the text `helloं` (i.e. `hello+U2306`) The unicode bytes are always at the end of the word.

I started with a simple elisp function that would print a message if a text that matches my criteria is found and saving the modified string to be searched into a variable:

```
(defun c-search ()
  "If word under cursor ends with U2350+U2381, search for word+U2306"
  (interactive)
  (if (string-match-p "म्" (thing-at-point 'word))
  (setq z (replace-regexp-in-string "म्$" "ं" (thing-at-point 'word)))
  (message "Should search  %s" z)))
```

Nothing gets printed when I evaluate this function. However, the following function that searches and replaces the string works fine:

```
(defun rrx ()
      (interactive)
      (setq z (replace-regexp-in-string "म्$" "ं" (thing-at-point 'word)))
      (message z))
```

How can I fix function `c-search` to perform a search for the string saved in variable `z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to write a custom elisp function that searches for a few variants of unicode text under a cursor and highlights their occurrences in the currently open file.

I took this as the task and wrote a function that *highlights* the variant of the symbol at point. It doesn't search for it, nor replace it. This way you can move freely while the matches are highlighted. Here's the function,

```lisp
(defun c-search ()
  "If word under cursor ends with U2350+U2381, highlight all
occurrences of word+U2306"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((bos (re-search-backward "\\_<"))
          (eos (re-search-forward "\\_>")))
      (goto-char bos)
      (when (re-search-forward ".*म्" eos)
        (highlight-regexp (replace-regexp-in-string "म्$" "ं" (match-string-no-properties 0)))))))
```

Notice it searches within the *symbol* (delimited by `\_<` and `\_>`) at point instead of the *word* (delimited by `\b`) at point, because (at least in Emacs Lisp mode) words are splitted at the character `म्`, so if you search until the end of the word, or if you use `(thing-at-point 'word)`, the search stops short of `म्`.

`hi-lock` saves the regexps it highlights in the variable `hi-lock-interactive-patterns`. The latest regexp it has highlighted is the car of the car of that variable, which means you can access it with `(caar hi-lock-interactive-patterns)` if you need it. For example, you can unhighlight the latest highlight with this function:

```lisp
(defun unhighlight-latest-regexp ()
  (interactive)
  (unhighlight-regexp (caar hi-lock-interactive-patterns)))
```